# how to bring up the menu from a 2.2 android app in android 4.4?

Tags: android, menu

I'm compiling an app developed on android V2.2 on a phone made for V4.4
I need to bring up the options menu with the "Physical menu button" (according to the V2.2 app instructions) but my phone does not have a physical menu button. the virtual button also does not appear.
Any recommendations on how to bring up the menu?

EDIT:

here is the manifest of the app:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.inte.indoorpositiontracker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:name="com.inte.indoorpositiontracker.IndoorPositionTracker"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MapViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MapEditActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.inte.indoorpositiontracker.MapViewActivity" />
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: do you not get the action overflow button in the action bar?

Comment: you dont see the menu option in the actionbar or the compatibility menu at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html has screenshots of what tyczj is referring to.

Comment: this is a screenshot from the main activity. http://imgur.com/TaVj3Uk no buttons at all.

Comment: do you have a custome theme set or something? post your manifest

Comment: manifest added to the main post

Comment: Did you try with a lower `android:targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: Thanks! it's working now! I put 10 in targetSdkVersion and the legacy menu option appeared. is there any way I can make this work with the action bar?